# Howto link a prestashop docker to an existing mysql server

Tags: mysql, docker, prestashop

I'm using the following Prestashop docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/prestashop/prestashop/

It so happens that I already have a mysql server running on the host, because that was included with the whole DirectAdmin panel.

The variable DB_SERVER does nothing if I specify localhost or the IP adres of my server. -p 3306:3306 is also not allowed, since that port is already in use.

How can a Docker container reach the host:3306 mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have your Prestashop installation inside a container and MySQL server running on the Docker host?

Unless configured differently, both the container and the host are in the same `bridge` network.

Verify that your container is in the `bridge` network:

```
docker inspect <container-name>

        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            }
        }
```

Notice the gateway IP address - this is the address of the docker host inside the `bridge` network. Use it as a `DB_SERVER` variable to connect to the MySQL.

Comment: I inspected my prestashop container and it was on gateway 172.17.0.1,  but visiting the site will result in a Bad Gateway page. docker run -ti --name some-prestashop -p 1083:80 -d \
 -v prestashop-volume:/var/www/html/ \
 -e DB_SERVER=172.17.0.1 \
 -e DB_NAME=shop \
 -e DB_USER=shop \
 -e DB_PASSWD=my-passwd \
 prestashop/prestashop

Answer (score 0):

One year later...

Like what **@NetworkMeister** said, but, IPAddress instead.

```
docker inspect <container-name> | grep IPAddress
```

In other words, I used `172.17.0.2` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking to do is to connect your container process with mysql server that is running on that host. To retain using `localhost` as the assignment of `DB_SERVER` you can do the following...

```
docker run --net=host <YOUR_CONTAINER_OPTIONS>
```

By doing this your container will able to reach the mysql service that is deployed on localhost:3306.